# Export Data Tier Application Logging

Tags: sql-server-2017

Is there a way to monitor or track when a Database is being exported using the Export Data Tier Application?

The reason is our users require DBO permissions when working with a Database but we just want to monitor if they are not doing a complete Export of the Database.